# I'm trying to read a buffer, line by line, as fast as possible

Tags: c++, linux

I've read a file into a buffer (mmap) but it's quite large and I have to perform a lot of operations on the data.

Each line (designated by \n) is independent of the rest, so I don't need to have any context.

I'd like to do this in a threaded way. I'm just not sure of the best approach here.

If I spawn X threads, what would be the fastest way to get this file read by them? Can I just be like "Thread 1, read from 0-X. Thread 2, read from X+1- Y, etc" ?

Comment: But before reading the buffer, how will you know where is the `\n`?

Comment: I would create several worker threads that each can deal with a single line. and a master thread which reads one line and passes a pointer of that line to each of the worker threads.

Comment: Well it seems quite quick to iterate through, character by character, comparing to '\n'. I think the computation happening in the thread will offset the potential hit for finding the position of every Nth \n.

Comment: If you are going to iterate character by character, you might as well read everything in one pass, right?

Comment: stdcall, that's a very interesting approach. I could just 'getline', pass it to the worker, have the worker do the heavy stuff, and just send do that until hte file is empty.

Comment: drum, but the threads do more than just read. They also compute based on the data. That's heavy, and it would be faster to have it done asynchronously across multiple threads.

Comment: If you need to know what's really fastest you generally have to benchmark alternative implementations, but one I'd put high on my list was memory mapping the file.  You haven't said how you're reading it yet.  You might want to try [`madvise`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) `MADV_SEQUENTIAL`.  If it's I/O bound there's no point worrying about threading - you're better off thinking about compression, a terser format, RAID, faster disks etc..  While each line's independent - does it matter what order they're processed in?

Comment: I am mmap'ing the file into memory, yes.

Comment: So - *if* order of processing's unimportant, start a thread per core (let's call that N threads), have each start at x/N into the file and scan/process their share of the lines.  No reason to separate the scanning from the proecssing - it'll just be another point of synchronisation for no benefit.  If order does matter and it's CPU intensive, then you may not be able to improve much on a single threaded approach anyway, as scanning time will be miniscule.

Comment: Yes, that is basically my though. I'm just not sure how to do that. I start the thread, then I just tell each one "read from here to here". How do I tell it to read "here to here" ? Like, which call would be best for this?

Comment: I don't know what you think "quite large is", but i think the fastest way will be to do it TonyD's way with multiple threads each processing their own zone, but NOT to mmap the file.  I would have each thread just read 4k .. 64k (test for performance) chunks using fread.  You could easily find that all the RAM mmap consumes will slow you down.  As soon as a thread reads its chunk, then it should scan for a line and process it.  Repeat until the end of the chunk is reached, at which point you read the next 4k chunk.  Stop after processing the 1st line that intersects the zone of thread + 1.

Comment: You know, I think you might have faster IO if you don't read from different points in the file at the same time.  Therefore, I think the fastest way will not be TonyD.  I think you want to read from one end of the file only.  A thread should try to read a line from the buffer, and if the buffer end is reached, invoke read to read more data.  I would copy the line being processed out of the buffer into a small line sized buffer in the thread, which would allow reusing of the fread buffer.

Comment: Silly idea: when you "read from here to here", you mean read all the _complete_ lines found in the "here to here" range.  Complete line is one where you know that the first character is in that range.  Then you handle corner cases of lines that spans two ranges.  Bit complex, you may be better off with stdcall's idea.

Comment: I did a little bit of basic benchmarking (hardcoded strings with operations done on them) and threading this does make it about 3-5x faster (and in reality it should be even more significant, especially since I'm explicitly usin g-O0 among other things).


I think I'll be going with the 'read line, send to thread' idea. This should work well.

Comment: Overhead of passing individual lines to working threads would be large. Pass larger chunks. Divide the file in N equal parts, then adjust so that part boundaries are on `\n` characters.

Comment: Yes, it's the 'dividing' and 'adjusting' that I don't get. I've got my thread spawned and I can give them what they need - the issue is determining how to split this file up in a sane way that doesn't break lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic assumptions are that you have N cores, M MB of available physical memory and F is the size of the file. The optimal result is when all cores and all physical memory are in use, but no paging. Typical figures might be 8 cores and 6GB available memory.

A reasonable starting point would be:

1. Use 1 master thread and (N-2) workers, leaving 1 thread for the O/S.
2. Allow each worker to use M/N MB of memory (about 750MB, but err on the low side)
3. Each thread reads a chunk of the file using low level binary I/O (depends on O/S) to fill its allocated memory.
4. Each thread searches for text lines, then quits.
5. Master spawns new threads as needed to process file (assuming F > M). Master also handles edge cases of lines spanning chunks.

This should keep all cores at close to max CPU, with the system thread doing most of the I/O. The I/O channel should be saturated until the file has been read, and I/O will overlap CPU. Important to check that there is no paging. Adjust the block size to maximise overlap.